# How to render a link as a button

Tags: 7, forms, navigation

I am using Drupal 7 and I would like to render a link (anchor tag) the same as a submit button. Does Drupal 7 allow for this (say by using the button type) or do I have to use CSS to accomplish this?

Comment: No need to add CSS, just add a class "button" in your link.

Comment: This worked great! I didn't know that you could do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to, and should, use CSS to style this.

```
.buttonize {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  padding: .5em;
  /* whatever other styles you want */
}
```

I added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HV7u/).

You can look this up, but I'll note that `appearance` is different on OS's

Comment: Thanks this is good to know. I didn't realize there was an appearance css tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, add 'btn' class to anchor tag. So simple!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Drupal default theme, you can try these classes:

**Add button**

button button-action button--primary button--small

**Save button**

button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit

**Form submit button**

button js-form-submit form-submit

You can use an element inspector on other admin pages to see what button classes can work for you, but these cover the most common cases for Bartik and Seven in D8. For Bootstrap, go with Sujith's answer about the btn classes. Here are the relevant links:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/